# Open wordpress nav menu in defizned size window?

Tags: wordpress, nav

How can I open a menu item in the wordpress menu in a new window with a defined size?

I need it to be like a normal window not a popup or iframe. Thanks!

more details: In the WordPress menu section, I have a link I would like to open in a new window not a new tab. I need it to open with specific dimensions like 900px * 500px for example (sort of like a popup).

Comment: I need more explanation to the problem so that I can give the right answer

Comment: see updated question

Answer (score 0):

Add onclick attribute to your wordpress nav like this `onclick="myFunction()"` and your wordpress nav

```
wp_nav_menu(
  array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'container'          => '',
    'items_wrap'         => '<ul><li><a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">Link</a></li>%3$s</ul>'
  )
);
```

create a javascript file, and create like this

```
function myFunction() {
  var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=900,height=500");
}
```

and in your functions.php

```
function your_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myfunction.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_scripts' );
```

Comment: hey, can you please explain the first step?